# Binding a Checkbox to a String

Tags: wpf, string, binding, checkbox

I've got a question about the binding of checkboxes.
Is it possible to bind a WPF checkbox to a string
with "true" or "false". 
I don't want to use the boolean variable in binding

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding someBooleanVariable}"/>
```

I want to to do something like

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding someStringVariable}"/>
```

I need that because I want to bind a part of my UI to a Hashmap containing strings. But the UI consists of Textboxes, Checkboxes and Radiobuttons. I want to bind my UI Elements to a function with a parameter for the key of the hashmap. And the function shall return the value of the given key as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and use a custom value converter that converts from string values to booleans. [This code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33216/Using-the-ConditionalValueConverter-to-evaluate-co) looks like it does this (and much more); [this gist](https://gist.github.com/907348) is much more basic but it's also a lot less code.